# How to calculate weights for a biased sampling?

Tags: probability, sampling

I am a polymer chemist foraying into the realm of statistical sampling of phase space. I apologize in advance if this is too basic a question.

I am following this resource to learn about biased sampling: [http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~tp/papers/pub084pre.pdf](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/%7Etp/papers/pub084pre.pdf).

The reason we perform biased sampling is to observe rare events taking place in the system of interest. So given a simple 1D random walk with probability of going to the left is equal to the probability of going to the right, we get $$p_{n,k} = \frac{1}{2^n} \binom{n}{k}$$.

I see that
\begin{align*}
\sum _{k=0}^n p_{n,k} = 1 \quad (1) 
\end{align*}

Furthermore, if I have a slightly more involved biasing potential $p$ like a local biasing potential, how do I rigorously find out what the weight is? Is the weight simply some normalization constant?

If my biasing potential is local, i.e. $p_{n,k,bias} = \frac{n+1-k}{n+2}$ (mentioned in the pdf above), I am told that the biasing weight is $W_{n,k} = \frac{n+1}{2^n}\binom{n}{k}$. What is the proof of this statement? Is there a general method of approaching a problem like this?

I would appreciate any advice you have for me.

Comment: Re "clearly:" Why not?  The Binomial Theorem says the sum of the $p_{n,k}$ equals $(p + 1-p)^n = 1.$  What do you mean by a "complicated" $p$?  Whether to weight something and how is ultimately a matter of (a) how you sample and (b) your estimation procedure: we need those details.

Comment: Oh you are right. I will change that statement! by complicated $p$, I mean, that if my biasing potential is local like that for uniform sampling, how would I calculate my weights.

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately, your question doesn't have enough detail for any definite answer.  Perhaps you are in a situation appropriate for a [probability-weighted estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horvitz%E2%80%93Thompson_estimator)?  I'm just guessing here, because it's unclear what a "biasing potential" really is.